# How to randomize textures that have an transparency/alpha channel?

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I can easily randomize textures but i dont know how to throw transparency in the mix.

In simpler worlds - How to randomize textures with transparency/alpha channel ?

Anyone can help ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to add transparency to randomization. It turned out i need to duplicate setup for randomization in that way i have exact node setup for both textures and alpha channel. Iv also added ON/OFF switch to randomization.
[image]